# I'm wondering why my Random.Range(1, 2) isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here, I'm wondering why I'm just getting "0" and not "1". (I'm using Unity, C#)

```
public int x;

void Start()
{
    x = Random.Range(0, 1);
}

public void Test()
{
    if(x == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("0");
    }
    else if(x == 1)
    {
        Debug.Log("1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your title mentions `Range(1,2)` which doesn't appear. Anyway, `UnityEngine.Random.Range(0,1)` will only ever return `0`. From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html): "`public static int Range(int minInclusive, int maxExclusive);`
Description
Return a random int within [`minInclusive`..`maxExclusive`) (Read Only).

This method will behave in the following ways:

**`maxExcusive` is exclusive, so for example` Random.Range(0, 10)` will return a value between 0 and 9, each with approximately equal probability.**"

Comment: Perhaps you should describe why you expect to ever get `1`, when the max value is defined to be exclusive?

Comment: @RufusL presumably because FM https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html says maxInclusive... but only for `(float, float)-> float` version... Quite confusing if one is not well versed in language and not super careful in reading the docs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Random.Range you should keep in mind the maximum value that you need to insert should always be greater than 1
For example:
**If you want to get "1" sometimes you need to set your maximum value to "2" instead of "1"**
So it should be like this:
x = Random.Range (0, 2);

So always **add 1 number to the maximum value** you need!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by *"the maximum value that you need to insert should always be greater than 1"*. The `Range` method definitely works with negative numbers.

Comment: The maximum value of the Random Range!
As it's syntax goes like this:
Random.Range(Minimum value, Maximum value)

Comment: Right, but it doesn't have to be greater than `1`. Also, why do you say *"sometimes you need to..."*. That implies that there are times when it's not necessary..?

Comment: Well if you want to get x = 1, you're gonna need to up the maximum value to 2 instead of 1

Comment: @RufusL I think what wAWEhd_ ment is it has to be 1 greater than the maximum expected output ;) Just phrased a bit confusing

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, sorry if i missed pronounce :)